# Can a nested ember.js route use a different model and still retain controller context?

Tags: ember.js

I have a basic person object

PersonApp.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string')
});

I have a route to find all people

```
PersonApp.Router.map(function(match) {                                                                                                 
    this.resource("person", { path: "/" }, function() {
        this.route("page", { path: "/page/:page_id" });
        this.route("search", { path: "/search/:page_term" });
    });
});
```

In my route I'm looking at the params coming in

```
PersonApp.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    selectedPage: 1,
    filterBy: '',
    model: function(params) {
        if (get(params, 'page_id') !== undefined) {
            this.selectedPage = get(params, 'page_id');
        } else {
            this.selectedPage = 1;
        }
        if (get(params, 'page_term') !== undefined) {
            this.filterBy = get(params, 'page_term');
        } else {
            this.filterBy = '';
        }
        console.log(this.selectedPage);
        console.log(this.filterBy);
        return PersonApp.Person.find();
    }
});
```

My nested routes are using a different model (not person directly) as they contain data that isn't persisted (and really only let me flip a bit on the controller)

Yet when I manually put something on the url or click a link that does a full blown transition the "params" coming into my model hook above are always empty.

Here is the basic page model I'm using (w/ search support)

```
PersonApp.Page = Ember.Object.extend({
    term: ''
});
```

When a user does a search I have a view that invokes transitionTo

```
PersonApp.SearchField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    keyUp: function(e) {
        var model = PersonApp.Page.create({term: this.get('value')});
        this.get('controller.target').transitionTo('person.search', model);
    }
});
```

Any way I can pass this "page" model to a nested view and still retain the basic "person" controller context (ie- so I can manipulate the view around this array of model objects)